# Save/Load GridView layout using SettingsService

Tags: c#, serialization, uwp

I am able to save my `GridView` layout by storing a `string` representation of the items in the `ItemsSource`. I then load that `string` representation from the `SettingsService` and set the `index` of the items accordingly.

The layout is changed by drag/dropping items in the `GridView`. Here is the code-behind:

```
private void MainGridView_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = e.OriginalSource as GridView;
    var items = grid?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<AppPage>;

    if (items != null)
    {
        var layout = "";

        // save settings
        foreach (var p in items)
        {
            p.PageIndex = items.IndexOf(p);
            // serialize pagename and pageindex
            layout += $"{p.PageName},{p.PageIndex}|";
        }
        _settings.MainMenuLayout = layout;
    }
}
```

Then when I load the application, I check for the `MainMenuLayout` setting and parse it out like so:

```
public void LoadMainMenu()
{
    var pages = new ObservableCollection<AppPage>
    {
        new AppPage("Payees", "ms-appx:///Assets/payee-180.png", typeof(Views.PayeesPage)),
        new AppPage("Bills", "ms-appx:///Assets/invoice-180.png", typeof(Views.InvoicesPage)),
        new AppPage("Payments", "ms-appx:///Assets/envelope-180.png", typeof(Views.PaymentsPage)),
        new AppPage("Checkbook", "ms-appx:///Assets/checkbook-180.png", typeof(Views.CheckbookPage)),
        new AppPage("Receipts", "ms-appx:///Assets/receipt-180.png", null),
        new AppPage("Categories", "ms-appx:///Assets/categories-180.png", typeof(Views.CategoriesPage)),
        new AppPage("Accounts", "ms-appx:///Assets/bank-180.png", typeof(Views.AccountsPage)),
        new AppPage("Budget", "ms-appx:///Assets/budget-180.png", null),
        new AppPage("Contacts", "ms-appx:///Assets/contacts-180.png", typeof(Views.ContactsPage)),
        new AppPage("Reports", "ms-appx:///Assets/charts-180.png", typeof(Views.ReportsPage)),
        new AppPage("Test", "ms-appx:///Assets/beaker-180.png", typeof(Views.TestPage)),
    };

    var layout = _settings.MainMenuLayout;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(layout))
    {
        // split on |
        var pagesSplit = layout.Split('|');

        foreach (var p in pagesSplit)
        {
            // then split on ,
            if (p.Contains(","))
            {
                var pageInfo = p.Split(',');
                var cur = pages.First(page => page.PageName == pageInfo[0]);
                cur.PageIndex = int.Parse(pageInfo[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    // sort based on index
    AppPages = new ObservableCollection<AppPage>(pages.OrderBy(p => p.PageIndex));
}
```

Is there a better way to serialize/deserialize the layout? I don't want to store the entire `AppPage` objects for every item, as there are additional properties that are unrelated to the layout.

Comment: What UI framework is this? WPF?

Comment: "I don't want to store the entire `AppPage` objects" Is there a reason why you don't create a tiny custom object containing only the data you want, and serialize that?

Comment: @svick It is a UWP project based on Template 10. I suppose I could create a new class with only the relevant information to be serialized... thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: I can post the XAML for the `GridView` as well if that would help at all, but I think it isn't really relevant to the C# code.

Answer (score 1):

At the recommendation of @svick, I decided to serialize the objects themselves. Rather than creating a custom object/stub, I just added `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the properties that I did not want to serialize.

Here is the new code for saving the layout:

```
private void MainGridView_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = e.OriginalSource as GridView;
    var items = grid?.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<AppPage>;

    if (items != null)
    {
        foreach (var p in items)
        {
            p.PageIndex = items.IndexOf(p);
        }
        // serialize items
        var layout = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
        _settings.MainMenuLayout = layout;
    }
}
```

Then I was able to simplify reading the layout from settings like so:

```
var layout = _settings.MainMenuLayout;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(layout))
{
    var pageStubs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<AppPage>>(layout);

    foreach (var p in pageStubs)
    {
        var cur = pages.First(page => page.PageName == p.PageName);
        cur.PageIndex = p.PageIndex;
    }
    // sort based on index
    AppPages = new ObservableCollection<AppPage>(pages.OrderBy(p => p.PageIndex));
}
else
{
    AppPages = pages;
}
```

The only properties of `AppPage` that get serialized are the `PageName` and `PageIndex`, which are the only properties used for this process.

Any further improvements are always welcome!